# Unitary Matrices in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

**Could anybody provide the examples of two unitary matrices which sum is also unitary**

Let A = $$
\left[
\matrix
{1&0\\
0&1\\}\right]
$$

Then what would be B?

I need to show that $ (A+B)(A+B)^* = I $ Please let me know another unitary matrix.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $A = I$ and $B$ is unitary then $AA^*+AB+BA+BB^* = I \implies 2B = I$ which is not possible, because then $BB^* = \frac{1}{4}I=I$

Comment: As pointed out, it is not true in general, but it is still an interesting question of whether there exists any pair of matrices for which the question is true.

Comment: So such kind of matrix does not exist?

Comment: For $A$ specifically equal to $I$, correct.  No such $B$ can exist.  Still trying to work out details if there exist any such pair $A$ and $B$ for which it works however.

Comment: Thanks a lot! looking forward to it!

Comment: The general case follows from this special case, since if $A$, $B$ and $A+B$ were unitary, the same would be true of  $I$, $A^{-1} B$ and $A^{-1}(A+B) = I + A^{-1} B$.

Comment: Would you elaborate more? @RobertIsrael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{A}= \{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ be the columns of $A$ and $\mathcal{B}=\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ the columns of $B$. Then since $A$ and $B$ are unitary [we know that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix#Equivalent_conditions) $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ are [orthonormal basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis). Now suppose by contradiction that $A+B$ is unitary, then we need $$\delta_{i,j}=\langle a_i+b_i,a_j+b_j\rangle =2\langle a_i,b_j\rangle+\langle b_i,b_j\rangle+\langle a_i,a_j\rangle=2\langle a_i,b_j\rangle+2\delta_{i,j}, \\ \implies \langle a_i,b_j\rangle = -\frac{\delta_{i,j}}{2}$$
where $\delta_{i,j}$ is the Kroenecker delta.
So we have $$b_j = \sum_{k = 1}^n\langle a_k,b_j\rangle a_k= -\frac{a_i}{2},$$
but then we get
$$\| b_j\|_2 = \frac{1}{2} \neq 1.$$
this is a contradiction.

Comment: That's interesting that such kind of unitary matrix does not exist. But I am getting weird homework problem i guess. Thanks for your detail! That explains a lot!

Comment: I am fairly new to the site. Yeah I'll accept all the answers that help me learn! Thanks again!